# Bots are picking up and dropping weapons in weird way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a TDS so it's time to make a mechanism to be able to pick up and drop weapons. I made it for the player and a new script for bots was based on player's one. So the problem is: I created an enemy prefab to be able to make as much of them as needed and if it is only one enemy while game is running then everything is fine: enemy passes through waypoins, picks up a weapon, then meets a better one and picks it up aswell dropping a worse one. But when I add a couple of new enemies things become weird as enemies don't pick up weapons (basically, a picked-up weapon doesn't become active) but just ignore them. At the same time the weapons on ground which are used to disappear when picked actually disappear so it doesn't make any sense. Here's the code of my realization. I hope we'll find a solution to this problem.
Thanks for you attention and sorry for my disgusting english!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class EnemyDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
//Current amount of ammo
public int currentAmmo;
private Vector3 offset;
//Weapons which are active in inventory.
//LABEL0
public GameObject _activeMelee;
public static GameObject activeMelee;
public GameObject _activeBottle;
public static GameObject activeBottle;
public GameObject _activeGun;
public static GameObject activeGun;
public GameObject _activePistol;
public static GameObject activePistol;
[HideInInspector] 
//ID of weapon which was active last time.
public int activeId;
//ID of weapon which is ready to be picked up.
private int activeQuestion;
//Weapon that is equipped before function ChangeWeapon().
private GameObject currentChange;
//Weapon that is ready to be picked up in function ChangeWeapon().
private GameObject groundWeapon;
public Transform enemy;
[HideInInspector] 
private bool ifThereIsSmthInHand;
[HideInInspector] 
//Can we move to next step? This becomes true when enemy's trigger works.
public bool mightDoNextTurn;
[HideInInspector] 
private string nameOfActive;
private string nameOfWeapon;
public GameObject[] arrayOfObjects;
public int[] arrayOfIds;
public int[] arrayOfAmmo;
[HideInInspector] 
public bool isFlying;
[HideInInspector] 
public float speed;
private float timeWhileFlying;
[HideInInspector] 
public float timing;
public int[] arrayOfValues;
private bool pickedAnEmptyWeapon;
public string nameactive;
public string nameWeapon;
public int question;

public static string getActiveWeapon () //LABEL1
{ 
    if (activeGun.activeSelf) { 
        return "Gun"; 
    } 
    if (activeMelee.activeSelf) { 
        return "Melee"; 
    } 
    if (activeBottle.activeSelf) {
        return "Bottle";
    }
    if (activePistol.activeSelf) {
        return "Pistol";
    }
    return "empty"; 
}

public static bool ifThereIsSomethingInHand ()//LABEL2
{ 
    if (activeMelee.activeSelf || activeGun.activeSelf || activeBottle.activeSelf || activePistol.activeSelf)
        return true;
    else
        return false; 
}
void Start ()
{ //LABEL3
    activeMelee = _activeMelee; 
    activeGun = _activeGun; 
    activeBottle = _activeBottle;
    activePistol = _activePistol;
    activeBottle.SetActive (false);
    activeMelee.SetActive (false); 
    activeGun.SetActive (false);
    activePistol.SetActive (false);
    offset = new Vector3 (0f, 0.9f, -0.5f); 
    mightDoNextTurn = false; 
    speed = 2;
    timeWhileFlying = 2; 
    activeId = 26; 
}

void Update ()
{ 
    ifThereIsSmthInHand = ifThereIsSomethingInHand (); 
    nameOfActive = getActiveWeapon (); 
    if (ifThereIsSmthInHand) { 
        if (mightDoNextTurn)
            ChangeWeapon ();
        else
            actionDrop (); 
    } else if (mightDoNextTurn)
        actionPick (); 
    nameactive = nameOfActive;
    nameWeapon = nameOfWeapon;
    question = activeQuestion;
}

private void actionDrop () //LABEL4
{ 
    if (currentAmmo == 0 && nameOfActive == "Gun") { 
        activeGun.SetActive (false); 
        arrayOfObjects [activeId].SetActive (true); 
        arrayOfValues [activeId] = 0;
        DropPos (); 
        activeId = 26; 
    } 
    if (currentAmmo == 0 && nameOfActive == "Pistol") { 
        activePistol.SetActive (false); 
        arrayOfObjects [activeId].SetActive (true); 
        arrayOfValues [activeId] = 0;
        DropPos (); 
        activeId = 26; 
    } 
}

public void deathDrop ()
{
    arrayOfObjects [activeId].SetActive (true);
    DropPos (); 
}

private void actionPick ()//LABEL5
{
    switch (nameOfWeapon) { 
    case "FireWeapon":
        activeGun.SetActive (true);
        break; 
    case "MeleeWeapon": 
        activeMelee.SetActive (true); 
        break; 
    case "BottleWeapon":
        activeBottle.SetActive (true);
        break;
    case "PistolWeapon":
        activePistol.SetActive (true);
        break;
    default: 
        break; 
    } 
    arrayOfObjects [activeQuestion].SetActive (false); 
    activeId = activeQuestion; 
    mightDoNextTurn = false;  
}

private void DropPos ()
{ 
    arrayOfObjects [activeId].transform.position = enemy.transform.position - offset; 
    arrayOfObjects [activeId].transform.rotation = enemy.transform.rotation; 
}

private void ChangeWeapon ()//LABEL6
{ 
    if (arrayOfValues [activeQuestion] > arrayOfValues [activeId]) { 
        if (activeMelee.activeSelf)
            currentChange = activeMelee; 
        if (activeGun.activeSelf)
            currentChange = activeGun; 
        if (activeBottle.activeSelf)
            currentChange = activeBottle;
        if (activePistol.activeSelf)
            currentChange = activePistol;
        currentChange.SetActive (false); 
        arrayOfObjects [activeId].SetActive (true); 
        DropPos ();
        activeId = 26; 
        arrayOfObjects [activeQuestion].SetActive (false); 
        activeId = activeQuestion; 
        mightDoNextTurn = false; 
        if (nameOfWeapon == "BottleWeapon") {
            activeBottle.SetActive (true);
        }
        if (nameOfWeapon == "MeleeWeapon") {
            activeMelee.SetActive (true); 
        }
        if (nameOfWeapon == "FireWeapon") {
            activeGun.SetActive (true);
        }
        if (nameOfWeapon == "PistolWeapon") {
            activePistol.SetActive (true);
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)//LABEL7
{ 
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Weapon") { 
        groundWeapon = other.gameObject; 
        activeQuestion = other.gameObject.GetComponent<IdOfWeapon> ().localId; 
        if (arrayOfValues [activeQuestion] == 0)
            activeQuestion = 26;
        if (activeQuestion >= 0 && activeQuestion <= 1000 && activeQuestion != 26) {
            if (activeQuestion < 31) { 
                nameOfWeapon = "MeleeWeapon"; 
            } 
            if (activeQuestion < 61 && activeQuestion >= 31) { 
                nameOfWeapon = "BottleWeapon"; 
            } 
            if (activeQuestion >= 61 && activeQuestion < 91) {
                nameOfWeapon = "FireWeapon"; 
            }
            if (activeQuestion >= 121 && activeQuestion < 151) {
                nameOfWeapon = "PistolWeapon";
            }
        }  
        mightDoNextTurn = true; 
    }
}

void OnTriggerStay (Collider other)//LABEL8
{ 
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Weapon") { 
        groundWeapon = other.gameObject;
        activeQuestion = other.gameObject.GetComponent<IdOfWeapon> ().localId; 
        if (arrayOfValues [activeQuestion] == 0)
            activeQuestion = 26;
        if (activeQuestion >= 0 && activeQuestion <= 1000 && activeQuestion != 26) {
            if (activeQuestion < 31) { 
                nameOfWeapon = "MeleeWeapon"; 
            } 
            if (activeQuestion < 61 && activeQuestion >= 31) { 
                nameOfWeapon = "BottleWeapon"; 
            } 
            if (activeQuestion >= 61 && activeQuestion < 91) {
                nameOfWeapon = "FireWeapon"; 
            }
            if (activeQuestion >= 121 && activeQuestion < 151) {
                nameOfWeapon = "PistolWeapon";
            }
        }
        mightDoNextTurn = true; 
    }
}
void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
{ 
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Weapon") { 
        mightDoNextTurn = false; 
        nameOfWeapon = ""; 
    } 
    activeQuestion = 26; 
    }
}
```

Note: enemy is allowed to drop a weapon for only two reasons: currentAmmo is equal to 0 or if he meets a better one (based on value).

Comment: the keyword static will mean this variable is shared with all instances of the script. This is what is causing you problems.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, I'll try me best to handle it know.

Answer (score 0):

the keyword static will mean this variable is shared with all instances of the script. This is what is causing you problems. – Catwood 1 hour ago - that's the solution